# Flipview orientation on touch device [UWP]

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have an application to read manga and comics, which uses a flipview to display the pages (images), and i want to add the option to browse the images by swiping from bottom to top , to do this, in the Page.Resources of the XAML i added this:

```
<Page.Resources> 
    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Name="VerticalOrientation">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>           
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

And the in the code behind i did this:

```
flipView.ItemsPanel = Resources["verticalOrientation"] as ItemsPanelTemplate;
```

When i test the app en my computer, it works as expected, i can browse the images with the keyboard and the scrollwheel. My issue is that that's not hapening using a touch device (a windows tablet), i can't swipe to the next or previous image.

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue. Please provide more details to narrow your issue. Firstly, please tested in a emulator to see if it can reproduce, if still can reproduce, please provide  a [mcve]. And please also provide the UWP target version, your touch device model and brand and the windows version of the device..

Comment: As you suggested me, i did a new project to isolate the issue and the problem was that there was no problem, it worked as expected. After adding more of the original code, i realized that i changed the orientation of the FlipView after adding items to it and thus causing the problem. So i moved the code a few lines up and problem solved. 
Gotta thank you anyways, without your comment i wouln't have found the problem.